# Empirical Measurements of Barr Body Ratio

Tags: genetics, dna, sex, sex-chromosome, gender

'Both X-chromosomes in a female have an equal chance of becomes a Barr body in each cell.' Every source I can find on Barr bodies claims this and I can think of no reason for why it may be wrong. What I want to know is if anyone has empirically tested this. Has anyone ever taken a model organism, measured the distribution of Barr bodies, and calculated exactly how far the result is from the 1:1 ratio that the theory predicts? Has anyone ever tested the Null Hypothesis of this statement, or has it just been accepted based on the theory alone?

Comment: Generally in science, accepted theories are not simply based on a *presumption* of accuracy just because it sounds right. While I don't have the citations you're looking for ([this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=barr+body+distribution) would be a good place to start looking), I'm certain it's based on strong empirical evidence, not guessing.

Comment: That is why I asked my question. Considering how wide-spread this claim is, there should be empirical evidence, but as far as I can tell there is none.

Comment: Did you start looking through the PubMed search I linked to? You can reverse-sort it by date published and start looking at the oldest papers first, as they're the ones most likely to have direct citations of the original work.